# Shorter name for terraform name_prefix

Tags: terraform

I wrote a new module for launch_configuration and autoscaling group with terraform. Everything works fine, but my only concern is the `name_prefix` value I get after the resources are created.

Is there a way to make the name shorter?

From `example-asg-20180303000844652900000002` to something much shorter, like:

```
example-asg-201803030
```

I know this name is generated randomly by terraform, but would be best if the name was shorter.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why do you want it to be shorter?

Comment: That's a good question... :) the account I'm using is shared one. Having a shorter name would be less confusing. Just because of those digits at the end.   Since you asked why, I am curios how other people are using the name_prefix parameter. Do people care much about their name and convention?  Thanks!

Comment: The point of using name prefix rather than name is to create uniqueness which is particularly useful when using `create_before_destroy` for zero downtime replacements. I don't really care what the rest of the junk on the end of the name is and I'm not sure why you would. Surely you only care about identifying the ASG by the start of the name?

Comment: That's true, I've looked more and read more about the name_prefix parameter. You are right, as long the name is readable and users know who's owning the resource, then everything should be fine. I am also using tags, this should be quicker to identify. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: This is a valid question. For many resources you have such short name_prefix limitations that naming conventions in those prefixes don't work.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the one way you have available to you is to manually construct the name attribute instead of using name_prefix. You interpolate some timestamp or whatever onto your name manually, with the inclusion of ignore_changes = ["name"] to prevent changes in the timestamp from causing your resource to be renamed every time you run terraform apply.

```tf
resource "some_resource" "foo" {
    # Change 8 for your desired substring length of timestamp
    name = "my-thing-${substr(replace(timestamp(), "/[-:]/", ""), 0, 8)}"
    lifecycle {
        ignore_changes = ["name"]
    }
}
```